# Verifying ethash output Ethereum block hash

Tags: mining, light-clients, dag, ethash

On the Ethash [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash), it mentions that a 16MB verification cache can be used to verify block hashes without generating the full DAG, but there are no further details on how this is done.

What's the verification algorithm?

EDIT: I'm not looking for a solution in Solidity where the blockhash is accessible. I'm looking for a way to validate that an Ethash output is valid off-chain.

Comment: https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/mining.html

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) at the Ethash wiki.

```py
def calc_dataset_item(cache, i):
    n = len(cache)
    r = HASH_BYTES // WORD_BYTES
    # initialize the mix
    mix = copy.copy(cache[i % n])
    mix[0] ^= i
    mix = sha3_512(mix)
    # fnv it with a lot of random cache nodes based on i
    for j in range(DATASET_PARENTS):
        cache_index = fnv(i ^ j, mix[j % r])
        mix = map(fnv, mix, cache[cache_index % n])
    return sha3_512(mix)

def hashimoto_light(full_size, cache, header, nonce):
    return hashimoto(header, nonce, full_size, lambda x: calc_dataset_item(cache, x))
```

Instead of generating the full dataset with `calc_dataset_item`, just the required dataset items for the single hash cycle are generated dynamically

Answer (score 0):

This code try :

```
function block_hash_validation(uint blockNumber, bytes32 blockHash) 
        constant returns(bool isValid) 
    {
        return (block.blockhash(blockNumber) == blockHash);
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear, I meant verification off-chain like with geth, not in Solidity.